# I am troubling to build git environment on IBMi

Tags: git, ibm-midrange

I am trying to build git environment on IBMi.
I use softwares as a follows.

- RDi
- EGit (eclipse)

When I configure remote repository on EGit,it occurred as afollows.

`ssh: connect to IP address port 22: Connection refused`

I have no idea to solve this error.
Please how to fix this error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sounds like a networking/service problem, not a git problem. Can you connect to said host/port using telnet to check that the port is open/working? If it is not, there's no way git will be able to use that remote.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  It's necessary to configure ssh key and enable sshd on remote machine ?

Comment: In order to be able to use ttat server as a git server thrugh ssh? Most definitely.

Answer (score 0):

The machine you have specified in your git url does not run the ssh server that git expects to talk to. This is typically GitHub or similar, not the IBM I itself unless explicitly configured so.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1. sshd is not started
2. network or firewall stopping ssh session on the specified port